# What is the correct way of creating textures for a map with Libgdx without tmx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I am making a top down style game using LibGdx that I want to be randomly generated each new game load.

I am using a sprite sheet with 8 x 8 sprites inside that need to be combined into 16 x 16 tiles. (I'm doing this to get more natural looking levels. I can explain this more if needed.)

I already have the algorithm to generate the array for what tile should be what.

But i'm stuck on how I should handle the tile classes.

I have this class called Tile

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;


public class Tile extends Sprite{ // Should I use sprite??? Seems wrong..

public byte id;

public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];

public static Tile grass = new GrassTile(0);

public Tile(int id) {
    this.id = (byte) id;
    if (tiles[id] != null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Tile Already Exists....");
    tiles[id] = this;
}

}
```

And I want to have multiple classes that exened this class for each tile. For example this is grass.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;


public class Tile extends Sprite{

public byte id;

public static Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];

public static Tile grass = new GrassTile(0);

public Tile(int id) {
    this.id = (byte) id;
    if (tiles[id] != null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Tile Already Exists....");
    tiles[id] = this;
}

}
```

Should these classes be extended off of a sprite? Or some other class from libgdx?

Also Keep in mind these tiles are going to be 16 x 16 that are made up of 4 smaller 8x8 sections of the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A great example provided by the Libgdx github page shows you how to achieve this by generating a TileMapLayer.  Assigning cells to the layer and then adding the layer to the map.

This snippet of code will help you achieve what you want. The original documentation is [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/bench/TiledMapBench.java)

More documentation here: [Libgdx Tile-maps](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps)

```
  public void create () {
            float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            camera.setToOrtho(false, (w / h) * 320, 320);
            camera.update();

            cameraController = new OrthoCamController(camera);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(cameraController);

            font = new BitmapFont();
            batch = new SpriteBatch();

            {
                tiles = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/maps/tiled/tiles.png"));
                TextureRegion[][] splitTiles = TextureRegion.split(tiles, 32, 32);
                map = new TiledMap();
                MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();
                for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++) {
                    TiledMapTileLayer layer = new TiledMapTileLayer(150, 100, 32, 32);
                    for (int x = 0; x < 150; x++) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                            int ty = (int)(Math.random() * splitTiles.length);
                            int tx = (int)(Math.random() * splitTiles[ty].length);
                            Cell cell = new Cell();
                            cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(splitTiles[ty][tx]));
                            layer.setCell(x, y, cell);
                        }
                    }
                    layers.add(layer);
                }
            }
            // for top down camera view
            renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        }
```

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that. I couldn't figure out how I would create a 16 x 16 tile from 4 8 x 8 tiles from the sprite sheet though.

Comment: what you said doesn't make sense? you want to make a 16 x 16 map?

Comment: No the map will be say 100 x 100 tiles.

Each tile needs to be 16 x 16.

I want to compose each tile from 4 8 x 8 tiles from the sprite sheet to create the single 16 x 16 tile.

I need to do this because some tiles will need to be created using different patterns of the 8 x 8 tiles loaded from the sprite sheet.

I hope that makes more since. If not let me know and I might have another way to explain it.

Comment: you will just need to design the end tiles seperately, i wouldn't say there is an easy way to manipulate the tiles after you draw them espescially as i don't know what the assets/end result will look like.

Comment: I guess a good example would be trees. If there are 4 of them in a bunch then I would render a different tile to make them look like a patch of trees. 

Here is a example image of the tree tiles.

http://gyazo.com/2ef375027038e1faf7d0814a5a559b05 

And what they can look like

http://gyazo.com/fdb5ae77a8c53f0ac5bc6f1bde418bc2

Im trying to move away from java2d and use libgdx for the performance benefits.

Comment: hmmm never actually implemented this way of tiling before, let me just have a deeper iook into it and i'll see if i find any resources that can help you

Comment: okay i get you, but wouldn't it be easier to have 5 different sprites for tress say one has one tree, two has two and thres has three and when you generate the code just generate them all randomly at the beginning so that all trees are drawn in different areas of the map yet having various trees drawn?

Comment: example: generate 1 tree randomly in the map at a random location, generate 2 trees randomly in the map at a different random location etc etc

Comment: That might work. But the player can harvest these materials as well as rocks flowers ect. So other tiles will need to have something similar. But if worse comes to worse I could change it to how you have described. It seems like it should be possible. I mean if java2d and drawing raw bitmaps could do it I should have a bit of fine control with libgdx aswell.

Comment: libgdx offers an array of features for tiles, but i think for each scenario you request just render the sprite differently on each update. Im sorry this isn't a solution but i hope i helped